# Cerrando preguntas que analizan un guión de cine o televisión

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre

Me gustaría proponer un uso quizás nuevo de la razón de votar por cerrar, Off Topic porque hace "Crítica, discusión o análisis de literatura española," lo cual no se permite según nuestras páginas de Help: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Ejemplo: [Meaning of "tener que hacer algo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32349/9385), que pregunta

> why does the speaker say "tuvieron que salir" instead of "salieron"? (¿Por qué el personaje dice "tuvieron que salir" en lugar de "salieron"?

*(Por cierto, estaría bien tener una traducción al español de la etiqueta [close-reasons](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons) -- quizás "justificación-de-cerrar".)*

Comment: El ejemplo que enlazas me parece una pregunta válida, muy en la línea de las que está haciendo Alan acerca de por qué se usa la forma verbal X (tener que + verbo) en vez de la forma Y (verbo simple). Ahora bien, la propuesta podría ser válida para preguntas en plan "¿Son los cien cañones por banda un reflejo del ansia del escritor por comer paella?", en los que sí se está pidiendo una interpretación de un texto literario. En todo caso, dado que ya tenemos un motivo de cierre por "off-topic", si nos tenemos que poner a listar todos los posibles motivos del "off-topic" no terminaríamos nunca.

Comment: creo que con eso de "Crítica, discusión o análisis de literatura española," se refiere más bien a cosas como 'la peli estuvo bien', o 'podía haber dicho esto en vez de eso', comentarios de ese tipo, pero lo que hace en el ejemplo es analizar el lenguage en un contexto, usos del lenguaje, matices, lo cual me parece válido